# Visual Studio No Source Available

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am really at a loss here, and have been trying to find a solution to this for several hours. I am lost. I get the following exception during an operation that was working the last time I checked.

`'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'Foreground'.`

It does not take me to where the error is occuring. It takes me to a page that says "No Source Available", and nothing else. I have tried locating the error by placing breakpoints in various places, but it seems to fail at different points during each run through. The InnerException is null.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957950/no-source-available-when-managed-exception-occurs-wpf-visual-studio-2010), as well as various articles from Google. I cannot figure out what is going on, and I do not know how to troubleshoot from here. The Visual Studio output doesn't appear to give any more detailed information, but I will paste it on request. Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm willing to be you have a missing resource. If you do something like:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource NoSuchResourceKey}" />
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Click Me" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Then you will get such an exception. We can even use a ComponentResourceKey to produce this exception:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=NoSuchResourceKey}}" />
</Style>
```

There are few things here that cause the issue. Normally, you would get a compiler error saying a resource doesn't exist when using `StaticResource`. Such as in this case:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Foreground="{StaticResource NoSuchResourceKey}" />
```

If instead, we had done:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Foreground="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=NoSuchResourceKey}}" />
```

Then you would get a different exception (XamlParseException), saying:

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '22'.

With an internal exception of:

> Cannot find resource named 'TargetType=System.Windows.FrameworkElement ID=NoSuchResourceKey'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Which all leads us to the real problem (a missing resource). The reason the first two examples don't give us a useful exception, is that we are not setting the `Foreground` property. We are setting the `Value` property on a `Setter` object. So when the resource is not found, `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is used. Which is perfectly valid for the `Setter.Value` property.

Later, when the `Style` is applied to the `Button` we get the exception, because that's when the `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is actually assigned to the `Button.Foreground` property.

To fix this issue, I'd search over your entire solution for `Property="Foreground"` and look for any instances that use a resource that doesn't exist.

I should add that you don't get an exception when using `DynamicResource`, because in that value passed to the `Button.Foreground` property is a "special value" (which allows deferred lookup). This "special value" won't assign the given property unless the resource is found.

Comment: The issue ended up being a bad reference in a resource dictionary I was using.

Comment: Is that a good reason to use DynamicResource? Is there a performance difference between static and dynamic?

Comment: @Tyrsius - No, that's not a good reason to use DynamicResource. There is additional overhead for using it versus StaticResource. The "special value" is retained and can the associated resource can b re-queried during runtime. Really, there just needs to be better error reporting in this case.

Comment: @CodeNaked +1 Nice detailed explanation. Some such error reporting also occurs if you try to assign a brush to a color.

Answer (score 1):

Have you rebuilt your project? Your PDB files may not match your DLLs, so VS may not be loading them. As for the error itself, it's likely a binding to a `Foreground` property is at fault.